# Writing unit test compatible for both asmx & wcf

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, asmx, integration-testing, mstest

How should I do automated unit testing of a web service(asmx) using visual studio 2012?.My web service contains lots of methods(108) with a dependency of some function to be executed before executing others. Secondly, same unit test will be used for unit testing WCF service(almost same counterpart) in future.so how to take care while writing unit test?

Answer (score 2):

There is a definition problem here. You are talking about 'unit testin WCF service', which is impossible, since unit tests -by definition- run in isolation, and can therefore not call a web service. In other words, you are using integration tests.

You shouldn't have duplicate tests. Create unit tests that test the business logic directly, without any WCF or asmx interaction in between. This way you will only have to test this once. Besides that you can create a few integration tests that test whether the call can be made to the web service, without really testing the business logic (since you already tested that).

> web service contains lots of methods(108)

Take a look at [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95). It describes a model where you define every operation as an object in such way that your web service can consist of a single method. This makes the web service very flexible, maintainable, and easy to test.